# How can I know when HTML5 Canvas finished drawing?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, resize

I'm a beginner to javascript. 
I'm trying to resize images on client side before uploading them to my server for storage
I have found a way to do it using HTML5 Canvas: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/how-to-develop-a-html5-image-uploader/

**My problem**: It kept on uploading blank image. I think the reason for the blank image is that canvas is not done drawing when I grabbed the image from canvas.
When I set a 3 second windows.timeout before grabbing image from canvas everything works fine. 
Is there a more reliable method than a timeout? Or is there any other method to do client-side image resizing?

The reason I'm doing client-side image resizing is because I'm dealing with people who uploads unnecessary big files and I think it is most efficient to do a client side image resizing.

Thank you for any hints/answers!

```js
//resize image
Resizeimage.resize(file);

//***if i wrap this part with timeout it works
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var data = canvas.toDataURL(file.type);

// convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
var bytestring;
if (data.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
  bytestring = atob(data.split(',')[1]);
else
  bytestring = escape(data.split(',')[1]);

//get imagetype
var mimeString = data.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

// write the bytes of the string to a typed array
var ia = new Uint8Array(bytestring.length);
for (var i = 0; i < bytestring.length; i++) {
  ia[i] = bytestring.charCodeAt(i);
}

// create a blob from array
var blob = new Blob([ia], {
  type: mimeString
});

//upload files
$scope.upload = $upload.upload({
  url: 'articles/imageUpload',
  method: 'POST',
  file: blob
    //update progress bar
}).progress(function(event) {
  $scope.uploadInProgress = true;
  $scope.uploadProgress = Math.floor(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
  //file upload success
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  $scope.uploadInProgress = false;
  $scope.uploadedImage = JSON.parse(data);
  $scope.isDisabled = false;
  //file upload fail
}).error(function(err) {
  $scope.uploadInProgress = false;
  console.log('Error uploading file: ' + err.message || err);
});
//***
```

```js
angular.module('articles').factory('Resizeimage', [
  function() {

    var imgSelectorStr = null;

    // Resizeimage service logic
    function render(src) {
      var image = new Image();

      image.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        
        //check the greater out of width and height
        if (image.height > image.width) {
          image.width *= 945 / image.height;
          image.height = 945;
        } else {
          image.height *= 945 / image.width;
          image.width = 945;
        }

        //draw (&resize) image to canvas
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);

      };
      image.src = src;
    }

    function loadImage(src) {
      // Create fileReader and run the result through the render
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(e) {
        render(e.target.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(src);
    }

    // Public API
    return {
      resize: function(src) {
        loadImage(src);
        return true;
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: Good explanation, but if you could post some code as well it would be great

Comment: @Breakpoint Thanks, I have inserted my code. BTW I'm trying to use MeanJS. So my code is angularJS on client side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is quite a simple one.

JavaScript will run one statement after another (and you need this because you want all statements executed when grabbing the image) as long as you dont attach to any events.

If you attach your code to an event (`image.onload` for example) this part of your code will wait for the event and the rest of your code will continue asynchronous.

So you are right - the image isn't drawn when you try to grab this.

Its bad style to solve it by a timeout (most inefficient/insecure) better solve this by wrapping your image-grabbing code in a function and run this function after your image re-size is done. It's like a callback you use to synchronize the asynchronous event.

**Example**

```js
/* setTimeout will behave like an event */
setTimeout(
  function(){
    $('console').append("<div>SetTimeout</div>");
     SynchCodeAfterTimeout();
  }, 1000);

AsynchCodeAfterTimeout();

function AsynchCodeAfterTimeout(){
    $('console').append("<div>AsynchCodeAfterTimeout</div>");
}

function SynchCodeAfterTimeout(){
    $('console').append("<div>SynchCodeAfterTimeout</div>");
}
```

```css
console{
  font-family: Consolas, monaco, monospace;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<console></console>
```

**Example with your code**

```js
render();

// Resizeimage service logic
function render() {
  var image = new Image();

  image.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

    //check the greater out of width and height
    if (image.height > image.width) {
      image.width *= 945 / image.height;
      image.height = 945;
    } else {
      image.height *= 945 / image.width;
      image.width = 945;
    }

    //draw (&resize) image to canvas
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
    /*timeout not needed its just there so the browser renders the canvas contents so you can see them when the alert pops up*/
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert('yey all the drawing is done (this is synchronous)');
    });
  };
  image.src = 'https://loremflickr.com/320/240';
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: So I was in the right direction to make the drawing synchronous. I'm sorry to ask this question, but how do I make it synchronous? I googled and read that I can do this by firing an event or using defered objects. But don't they require checking when canvas is ready?

Comment: as i pointed out in my answer - wrap all your image-grabbing code in a function that can be accessed from the last part of your re-sizing code and call it like I called `SynchCodeAfterTimeout()`.

Comment: As far as i can say without testing it, you should call the code from the end of the `.onload` in `function render(src)`

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough explanation and example! You are the most awesome! So canvas is actually blocking.. But the onload makes the whole block of code asynchronous... Now it makes more sense :)

Comment: Man, you help me so much!

Comment: This answer is very specific and does not work at the moment you need to do a lot of treatment after drawing. A better solution would be to be able to catch whatever event is fired once the drawing is done.

Answer (score -2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.onload = function(){
         //Whatever you want to do when it has finished loading here
     }
</script>
```

You can place this piece of code inside your HTML or somewhere in your JavaScript files only then without the script tags ;)

Hope this works for you :D

Comment: this will not work if, the objective is to draw image and add text to the canvas and if the data to be written is coming from an api,.